# How to set Foreground layer and Background Layer of logo for Flutter in vscode?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have been following a flutter tutorial. Where Android studio was been used. But I was doing flutter code in vscode.

But I found out that "Configure Image Asset" setting is available only in Android Studio.

Now I can't use round logo or foreground, background logo from vscode.

How can I set round logo for flutter app by using vscode?

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter VS Code extension does not contain any equivalent feature to Android Studio's "Configure Image Asset" so (for now, at least) you'll need to use Android Studio for that.